# How to submit form data using restify and post?

Tags: javascript, node.js, restify

I want to print an input value using restify and post route, but it's not working. The form.html page opens and upon submitting, I see this in URL:

**http://localhost:8081/?name=dsf**

But I don't see any message in console. Am I doing something wrong?

Here's my code:

**select.js**

```
var restify=require('restify');
var server=restify.createServer();
var mysql=require('mysql');
server.listen(8081, function(){
    console.log("%s is running at %s", server.name, server.url);
});
var pool=mysql.createPool({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: '',
    database: 'books'
});
server.get(/\/?.*/, restify.serveStatic({
    directory: __dirname,
    default: 'form.html'
}));
server.post('/hello/', function send(req, res, next){
    pool.getConnection(function(err, connection){
        if(err){
        }else{
            var table=req.body.name;
            console.log(table);
        }
    });
});
```

**form.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Both files are in C:/restify folder.

Comment: To start with, add a console.log statement to print out the err if it exists.

Answer (score 1):

`action` attribute is missing in your `<form>` tag. Try to set it to `action="/hello/"`. Does it solve your problem?

Comment: This was a mistake. I corrected it but still same response.

Comment: Here: `var table=req.body.name;`. Are you sure that it shouldn't be like: `var table=res.body.name;`? **res** instead of **req**

Comment: Yes, pretty sure.

Comment: I don't know how much you know Restify but look here: http://restify.com/ I'm pretty sure that in your `server.post()` function there is some mismatch. Try removing name of your `send` funciton. Leave it like this: `function(req, res, next)`